# Plot legend faded, how do I fix this?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, data-visualization

I have been trying to get the legend for my plot but the colours on the legend are really faded and therefore it is difficult to see which line is which, does anyone know how to fix this?

[image: screenshot of plot]

Here is the code in case anyone wants to see.

Thank you

```
import pandas as pd
import glob 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import find_peaks

path = r'C:\Users\benjy\impedance_measurements'
all_files = glob.glob(path +"/*.csv")

print(len(all_files)/10)
data = np.ndarray((8, 200000))
x_axis = range(100, 20000100, 100)

for i in range(0,8):

    dataset = np.ndarray((10, 200000))

    for j in range(10):

        df = pd.read_csv(all_files[10*i + j], skiprows=8, usecols=[3])
        # this line needed as otherwise cannot put into row of an array 
        df_num = df.values.ravel()
        dataset[j,:] = df_num[0:200000]
        

    mean = np.mean(dataset, axis=0)
    data[i,:] = mean

plt.plot(x_axis, data[0], label='steps 1 and 5 cemented', linewidth=0.2 )
plt.plot(x_axis, data[1], label='steps 1 and 5 cementless', linewidth=0.2)
plt.plot(x_axis, data[2], label='step 1 cemented & 5 cementless',  linewidth=0.2)
plt.plot(x_axis, data[3], label='step 1 cemented', linewidth=0.2)
plt.plot(x_axis, data[4], label='step 1 cementless & 5 cemented', linewidth=0.2)
plt.plot(x_axis, data[5], label='step 1 cementless', linewidth=0.2)
plt.plot(x_axis, data[6], label='step 5 cemented', linewidth=0.2)
plt.plot(x_axis, data[7], label='step 5 cementeless', linewidth=0.2)

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Isn't it affected by linewidth, or can't it be improved by setting `linewidth=1`?

Comment: That worked but is there a way to keep the linewidth thin and have the clear legend, the signals are quite noisy so it would be easier for me to observe when they are thin?

Comment: How about making a separate legend?

Comment: how do you mean? By putting all the labels in the plt.legend()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how to make legend that is independent of the plot:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
label = ['steps 1 and 5 cemented','steps 1 and 5 cementless','step 1 cemented & 5 cementless','step 1 cemented','step 1 cementless & 5 cemented','step 1 cementless','step 5 cemented','step 5 cementeless']
color = ['tab:blue','tab:orange','tab:green','tab:red','tab:purple','tab:brown','tab:pink','tab:gray']
handles = [Line2D([0], [0], marker='', color=color[i]) for i in range(len(color))]
plt.legend(handles, label)
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can edit the linewidth of the line in the legend alone (not affecting the plot) with:

```
for legobj in leg.legendHandles:
    legobj.set_linewidth(4)
```

### Complete Code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

N = 10000
x = np.linspace(0, 10, N)
y1 = np.sqrt(x) + 1/10*np.random.randn(N)
y2 = np.exp(-x) + 1/10*np.random.randn(N)


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(x, y1, label = 'signal 1', linewidth = 0.2)
ax.plot(x, y2, label = 'signal 2', linewidth = 0.2)

leg = ax.legend(frameon = True)

for legobj in leg.legendHandles:
    legobj.set_linewidth(4)

plt.show()
```

[image]